# Xamarin Forms x-axis overflow with Vertical Collection View

Tags: css, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a screen on my application that uses a CollectionView and a grid to display information to the user. It looks all fine and well however although there is padding on the grid, the items on the right hand side of the grid do not appear to be following the padding.[image: Image of screen]

As you can see, the 'Employees' item does not have any padding on the right of it.

I believe that the issue has to do with the row definitions:

```
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="200"></RowDefinition>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="200"></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

As I have specified a height of 200 and a width of 200 to make the items a square. Is there a way to dynamically resize the items to fit the screen without them appear to overflow on the x-axis while also keeping the shape as a square?

If I replace the values with `*`, nothing appears on the screen.

A way I thought about implementing this would be to set Width of the column == to the height of the row however I don't really understand how I could do that here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try  to use a `StackLayout` to wrap the `CollectionView`, and set padding for it.
For `GridItemsLayout`, you can use the following properties.for example:

```
  VerticalItemSpacing="10"
  HorizontalItemSpacing="10"
```

I have created a demo , the `xaml` is :

```
  <StackLayout Padding="6" BackgroundColor="LightGray">
        <CollectionView  x:Name="collectView" >
            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout >
                <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical"
                    Span="2"
                    VerticalItemSpacing="10"
                    HorizontalItemSpacing="10"/>
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate >
                <DataTemplate  >
                    <Grid  BackgroundColor="Green" >
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="200"></RowDefinition>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="200"></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label 
                            TextColor="White"
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.Column="0" 
                            Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </StackLayout>
```

**Note:**
We need update the XF nuget to the latest version.
Because the older version maynot include the property `VerticalItemSpacing` and `HorizontalItemSpacing`.

The result is:
[image]